# Is Atom with Vim packages of VS STudio with VIM plugin for Mac better

Tags: visual-studio, atom-editor, vim-plugin, neovim

I'm a VI user from long ago. I've been using Atom with ex-mode and vim-mode-plus packages for a few years now, but was thinking of switching to VS studio with the Vim plugin (and perhaps neovim). Has anyone tried both who could provide insights? What do you prefer/miss when switching, either direction? FYI I'm mostly working with React, git, JSON, in-browser stuff.

Many thanks!

Comment: Read the announcement https://github.blog/2022-06-08-sunsetting-atom/ and you  will see this question no longer is needed to be discussed.

Comment: Wow @LexLi Thank you I had no idea about this. Do you recommend VSC, or visual Studio? I'm having trouble understanding how to start a React app within Visual Studio.

Comment: Tool recommendation is off topic here on Stack Overflow. Both VS2022 and VS Code have excellent JS/React support if you use a search engine to learn.